# empty an array before the destroy call

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I display an array using this syntax on the template :

```
{{ numbers }}
```

How can I re-render the emptied array before calling the destroy method ?

```
destroy () {
    this.numbers = []
    this.$destroy()
}
```

This empties the array (app.numbers = [] in the console), but it does not refresh the `{{ numbers }}`.

Same if I put the code inside the "beforeDestroy" hook :

```
beforeDestroy () {
        this.numbers = []
}
```

How can I properly re-render the `{{ numbers }}` array before the destroy ?

Without using a setTimeout. Because of course this works :

```
destroy () {
    this.numbers = []
    setTimeout(()=>this.$destroy(), 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use the $nextTick method to update the real DOM after the data change :

```
destroy () {
    this.numbers = []              
    this.$nextTick(()=>this.$destroy())
}
```

A user (can't see is username) found the correct answer but deleted it since. If you are the user, I'll remove my answer so you can answer and have the credit.